# Eclipse Plugin: Opening a New Window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When developing an Eclipse plugin, what's the best practice for opening a new window?

Comment: What do you mean by 'New Window'? Do you want to show a dialog, a wizard, or a complete Eclipse window (as done by 'Window > New Window')?

Comment: It's pretty much a standard control gui (start a job, pause it, resume it), not something like a wizard where you can click "next, next, next, next, finish". I need the gui to change as the user makes input or when an operation in the background calculated something.